# python key dict error multilevel dict

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I'm not entirely sure why im getting a dictionary key error. I'm trying to create a multi level dict with = sign and getting a key error on metrics, but not on the first two.

```
doc['timestamp']
```

and

```
doc['instance_id']
```

both work fine, but when it gets to metrics it gives me a metrics key error. I'm not entirely sure why.

```
doc = {}
doc['timestamp'] = datetime.now()    
#doc['instance_id'] = get_cloud_app_name()
doc['instance_id'] = "MyMac"

cpu_dict_returned = get_cpu_info()
doc['metrics']['cpu_usage']['user_cpu'] = cpu_dict_returned['user_cpu']
doc['metrics']["cpu_usage"]['system_cpu'] = cpu_dict_returned['system_cpu']
doc['metrics']["cpu_usage"]['idle_cpu'] = cpu_dict_returned['idle_cpu']
doc['metrics']["cpu_usage"]['cpu_count'] = cpu_dict_returned['cpu_count']
```

Answer (score 5):

You must create the sub-dictionnaries before using them:

```
doc = {}
doc['timestamp'] = datetime.now()    
doc['instance_id'] = "MyMac"

cpu_dict_returned = get_cpu_info() 
doc['metrics'] = {}
doc['metrics']['cpu_usage'] = {}
doc['metrics']['cpu_usage']['user_cpu'] = cpu_dict_returned['user_cpu']
doc['metrics']["cpu_usage"]['system_cpu'] = cpu_dict_returned['system_cpu']
doc['metrics']["cpu_usage"]['idle_cpu'] = cpu_dict_returned['idle_cpu']
doc['metrics']["cpu_usage"]['cpu_count'] = cpu_dict_returned['cpu_count']
```

Comment: Thanks, I never knew that I usually create the dict by defining the structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this more succinctly using a dictionary comprehension:

```
doc = {}
doc['timestamp'] = datetime.now()    
doc['instance_id'] = "MyMac"

cpu_dict_returned = get_cpu_info() 
doc['metrics'] = {
    'cpu_usage':
        {k: cpu_dict_returned.get(k) 
         for k in ['user_cpu', 'system_cpu', 'idle_cpu', 'cpu_count']}
}
```

Note that the sub dictionary `cpu_usage` is first created, and then the nested dictionary is inserted.